# Subsetting by row value in R

Tags: r, subset, lubridate

Firstly apologies if this has been answered else where I have searched all over for this but cannot find the answer. My problem may be due to the way I am searching for info and so I decided to use StackOverflow so I can present my problem with examples.

I have five minute OHLC data DIA_5.csv which I have then added a DayOfYear column to using Lubridate;

`library(lubridate)`
`DIA_5[,6]<- yday(DIA_5[,1])`

Which looks like this;

```
    Date                Open        High        Low         Close       DOY 
1   2015-09-21 09:30:00 164.6700    164.7100    164.3700    164.5300    264
2   2015-09-21 09:35:00 164.5300    164.9000    164.5300    164.6400    264
3   2015-09-21 09:40:00 164.6600    164.8900    164.6000    164.8900    264
4   2015-09-21 09:45:00 164.9100    165.0900    164.9100    164.9736    264
5   2015-09-21 09:50:00 164.9399    165.0980    164.8200    164.8200    264
```

What I wanted to do was create a new d$f with the first column starting with the individual day of year numbers, then I would fill this new d$f by subsetting data from the original OHLC d$f using the day of year number. The aim of this is so that in the new d$f I can extract the MAX value from all the highs on day x and bring it to column on the new d$f and so on with the other variables. The closest I could get to this goal was by using the following code however, this returns me all the values from the OHLC and I cannot find away to change this so that only the day of year number is brought across to the new d$f.

`DF<-DIA_5[match(unique(DIA_5[,6]), DIA_5[,6]),]`

```
  row.names DATE    OPEN    HIGH    LOW CLOSE   DOY
1   1   2015-09-21 09:30:00 164.67  164.7100    164.370 164.5300    264
2   79  2015-09-22 09:30:00 162.62  162.9600    162.620 162.7544    265
3   157 2015-09-23 09:30:00 163.26  163.3800    162.980 163.1400    266
4   235 2015-09-24 09:30:00 161.12  161.3700    161.060 161.2300    267
5   313 2015-09-25 09:30:00 163.81  163.9100    163.570 163.5800    268
```

Despite having more data than needed using the above code I decided to try subsetting the data. So from the above I wanted in the row next to 264 to use this value as a filter on the main OHLC d$f then extract the highest value in the column of highs. Using

```
DF[,6] <- max(subset(DIA_5[,3], yday(DIA_5[,1]) == DF[,6] ))
```

gave me

```
Warning message:
In yday(DIA_5[, 1]) == DF[, 6] :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

It did give a new column  on d$f but this had the same value repeated.

```
row.names   DATE    OPEN    HIGH    LOW CLOSE   DOY
1   1   2015-09-21 09:30:00 164.67  164.7100    164.370 164.5300    179.02
2   79  2015-09-22 09:30:00 162.62  162.9600    162.620 162.7544    179.02
3   157 2015-09-23 09:30:00 163.26  163.3800    162.980 163.1400    179.02
4   235 2015-09-24 09:30:00 161.12  161.3700    161.060 161.2300    179.02
5   313 2015-09-25 09:30:00 163.81  163.9100    163.570 163.5800    179.02
6   391 2015-09-28 09:30:00 162.04  162.0600    161.660 161.7100    179.02
```

I tried using my subset syntax to pull the max high value from a random DOY number and it seems to work fine;

```
h <- max(subset(DIA_5[,3], yday(DIA_5[,1]) == DF[1,6] ))
```

But I just cannot find out how to do this so that it creates a new column of the `MAX` value in the high column on `x` day of year.

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: did you try using the package `data.table`? you can try using the _by_ parameter in the expression

Comment: I think you should check `dplyr` tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr`.

I created some fake data which looks like this and stored it in `df`:

```
    Date     Open    High    Low    Close DOY
1 2015-09-21 164.6700 164.710 164.37 164.5300 264
2 2015-09-21 164.5300 164.900 164.53 164.6400 264
3 2015-09-21 164.6600 164.890 164.60 164.8900 264
4 2015-09-22 164.9100 165.090 164.91 164.9736 265
5 2015-09-22 164.9399 165.098 164.82 164.8200 265
6 2015-09-22 162.6200 162.960 162.62 162.7544 265
7 2015-09-23 163.2600 163.380 162.98 163.1400 266
8 2015-09-23 161.1200 161.370 161.06 161.2300 266
9 2015-09-23 163.8100 163.910 163.57 163.5800 266

library(dplyr)
x <- df %>% 
  group_by(DOY) %>% 
  filter(High == max(High)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
x
        Date     Open    High    Low  Close DOY
1 2015-09-21 164.5300 164.900 164.53 164.64 264
2 2015-09-22 164.9399 165.098 164.82 164.82 265
3 2015-09-23 163.8100 163.910 163.57 163.58 266
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that, could you provide more details?

Answer (score 1):

`aggregate` is a fine 'one liner' for this

```
#simulate some time series and place in data.frame
set.seed(1)
d = data.frame(replicate(5,cumsum(rnorm(2000))))
d$doy = sort(sample(1:364,2000,replace=T))
print(d[d$doy==1,])

          X1          X2         X3         X4         X5 doy
1 -0.6264538 -0.88614959 -1.1346302 -0.6188271  0.2637034   1
2 -0.4428105 -2.80840448 -0.3700731 -1.7282490 -0.5657484   1
3 -1.2784391 -1.18870374  0.2006371 -3.8985843 -2.0273832   1
4  0.3168417 -0.66943383 -1.1510569 -3.9298873 -0.3433930   1
5  0.6463495 -0.72528376 -3.1809423 -4.1902858 -1.8877173   1
6 -0.1741189 -0.02886615 -2.5904637 -3.6558553 -2.0786045   1
7  0.3133101  0.02464952 -4.0035337 -4.2152947 -1.0623928   1
8  1.0516348 -1.28563397 -2.3931921 -2.6069245 -0.5152666   1
9  1.6274162 -3.40870003 -0.5527496 -2.0502848  0.2398875   1

#aggregate data by DOY and compute some statistics for each column
maxPerDOY.df = aggregate(d[1:5],list(doy=d$doy),max)
print(head(maxPerDOY.df,3))

  doy       X1          X2         X3         X4        X5
1   1 1.627416  0.02464952  0.2006371 -0.6188271 0.2637034
2   2 3.223652 -2.76920768  0.8155484 -1.8646623 2.1378466
3   3 3.216576 -3.39431265 -0.8062283 -0.6656144 2.9014736
```